# FileUtils not appending string to a file

Tags: java, java-8, netbeans-8

I'm using the code below to append string to a file.

```
File file = new File (rr);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "String to append",true);
```

I got the "true" underlined with tip error "incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String". What I'm missing ?

**UPDATE**
I'm using Java 8 with netbeans8.2 + Apache Commons IO 2.5

Comment: FileUtils is what?

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to java. However, I'm using "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;"

Comment: Your arguments are wrong. See the docs: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean) - You have to provide a String representing the encoding before the boolean.

Comment: What compiler/IDE/java version are you using?

Comment: I'm using netbeans 8.2 with Java 8

Comment: @AndrewLi There exists an overload that does match the specified argument types: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean) - it is deprecated in version 2.5 of commons.io. Maybe theres an IDE setting that hides deprecated API enabled. I don't know netbeans.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Yeah, it is deprecated, and that's probably why it won't see it.

Comment: If you can live without the dependency to a 3rd party library, you can simply use the standard Java: [`Files.write(Paths.get(rr), Collections.singleton("String to append"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)…

Comment: @Holger, great!!. And If I can't live without ? which library I have to have ?

Comment: I don’t know. I avoid 3rd party libraries when there is an equivalent built-in functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to have more idea about which overloaded version you need. There are multiple overloaded versions, which actually doesn't have the signature what you expect.

Refer to the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).